# Is Shariah a compulsion for a practising Muslim, can it be like I follow only the Quran and dont listen other teachings like Hadith and shariah?

Tags: quran, sharia, hadith-interpretation, quran-translation, apostasy

Assalamu-alaykum rahmatullahi wabara-katuh,
 My point is why follow rules interpreted by the others
when you can solely rely on the Quran itself.

I deny any teachings by "self-declared elders" of Islam i.e. after the prophet.

I openly condemn some part of the shariah law some of the aspects like Apostasy, court appearance of a rape victim to mention a few.

"I deny interpretation of rules Quran by others".
thank you,

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To leran more about our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your post this looks more like a statement than a question. If you condemn shari'a you are out of the folds of Islam as shari'a is Allahs ruling. You can't rely on Qur'an only and you can't rely on your interpretation of the Qur'an as actually nobody has such high standards in Arabic to understand it as it was understood when revealed and without extra input we wouldn't know the circumstances of revelation.

Answer (score 2):

Salam-alaykum;

Only "Relying on the Quran" is not sufficient, Quran itself says:

47:33

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَطِيعُوا اللَّهَ وَأَطِيعُوا
> الرَّسُولَ وَلَا تُبْطِلُوا أَعْمَالَكُمْ
>
> O you who believe! obey Allah and obey the Messenger, and do not make
> your deeds of no effect

4:59

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَطِيعُوا اللَّهَ وَأَطِيعُوا الرَّسُولَ وَأُولِي الْأَمْرِ مِنْكُمْ فَإِنْ تَنَازَعْتُمْ فِي شَيْءٍ فَرُدُّوهُ إِلَى اللَّهِ وَالرَّسُولِ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ تُؤْمِنُونَ بِاللَّهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ ذَلِكَ خَيْرٌ وَأَحْسَنُ تَأْوِيلًا
>
> Believers, obey God, His Messenger, and your (qualified) leaders. If you have faith in God and the Day of Judgment, refer to God and His Messenger concerning matters in which you differ. This would be a more virtuous and a better way of settling differences.

Who are qualified leaders (أُولِي الْأَمْرِ)?